# JQuery Post sends arrays and it returns the successful arrays in PHP but when the page is loaded nothing shows up?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, session

So what happens is that I use JQuery to post three arrays to a PHP script, the PHP script takes these $_POST's and then sets them as $_SESSION variables each. I then echo or print_r it to the script page and JQuery returns that output in the console with console.log. It seems to have gotten through successfully. However when I load the page it shows the array names but they are empty. Why?

JQuery code:

```
var postnames = stripnames;
var postqty = stripqty;
var postprices = stripprices;

if (stripqty[0] != 0 && stripqty[0] != null) {
    $.post("php/submit.php", { 'postnames':postnames, 'postqty':postqty, 'postprices':postprices }, function(returned) { 
        console.log(returned);
        routput = returned;
    });

    //Now we redirect our customer to the information filling in page.
    //window.location.assign(window.location.hostname + "php/submit.php");

} else {
    document.getElementById('outputresult').innerHTML = "Please enter a quantity for at least one strip box.";  
}
```

PHP Code for submit.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'session.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sell to Us</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
print_r($_SESSION['snames']);
?>

</body>
</html>
session.php
<?php
session_start();

include 'session.php';

?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Sell to Us</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
print_r($_SESSION['snames']);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

session.php:

```
<?php

    $_SESSION['snames'] = $_POST['postnames'];
    $_SESSION['sqty'] = $_POST['postqty'];
    $_SESSION['sprices'] = $_POST['postprices'];


?>
```

Here is the JQuery output:

```
"6b99aca9426f41fbbeaf4e291115ba7d

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Sell to Us</title>

</head>



<body>



Array
(
    [snames] => Array
        (
            [0] => Ultra Blue 25
        )

    [sqty] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [sprices] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
        )

)


</body>

</html>"
```

Then here is what shows up on the page from my browser when I load it:

```
6b99aca9426f41fbbeaf4e291115ba7d Array ( [snames] => [sqty] => [sprices] => )
```

The number at the start is the session ID. I can post the session ID that shows up on the main page where the JQuery is at but I doubt it really matters since it has nothing to do with the PHP Session variable handled over there? Or does it? I did check and the numbers matched. Maybe I didn't look closely enough.

If you guys want to see the live working version then I'd be happy to link to it here and post the DropBox URL's to each file for the latest working version.

EDIT: I closed my browser, about to turn off the PC for the night but apparently the JQuery is returning the same kind of output as normal but when I load the PHP script directly in the browser like before nothing shows up.

EDIT 2/2/15

```
<?php
session_start();

//We have to use isset because if we don't then ever subsequent pageload will overwrite the information in SESSION with nothing since we are not posting anything those times. So we check to see if POST isset so we know if there is no new information then to keep the old information.

//if(isset($_POST['postnames'])) unset($_SESSION);


if(isset($_POST['acceptpost'])) {

    unset($_SESSION);
    echo('Posted');

    $_SESSION['snames'] = $_POST['postnames'];
    $_SESSION['sqty'] = $_POST['postqty'];
    $_SESSION['sprices'] = $_POST['postprices'];

    //if(isset($_POST['postnames'])) $_SESSION['snames'] = $_POST['postnames'];
    //if(isset($_POST['postqty'])) $_SESSION['sqty'] = $_POST['postqty'];
    //if(isset($_POST['postprices'])) $_SESSION['sprices'] = $_POST['postprices'];

}

echo("There are " . count($_POST['postnames']) . " variables to be written.");



?>
```

This is my current session.php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you browse to the php script the `$_POST` array is empty, because you didn't send any data via post with that request. Because of this you overwrite your session variables in session.php:

```
$_SESSION['snames'] = $_POST['postnames'];
$_SESSION['sqty'] = $_POST['postqty'];
$_SESSION['sprices'] = $_POST['postprices'];
```

Thus `print_r($_SESSION['snames']);` outputs nothing.

To solve your problem you should only write to the session variables when the jquery ajax call really send the post data. There are several ways to achieve that, e.g.:

```
if(isset($_POST['postnames'])) $_SESSION['snames'] = $_POST['postnames'];
if(isset($_POST['postqty'])) $_SESSION['sqty'] = $_POST['postqty'];
if(isset($_POST['postprices'])) $_SESSION['sprices'] = $_POST['postprices'];
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! You don't know how long I've been trying to figure this out, I was about to switch to ASP.NET or something else entirely just because of this. Thank you. :)

Comment: You got me this far, thank you. However I have a new problem. The variable gets updated only once apparently. I can't post again with my new information, it won't take it and it keeps displaying the old one. Why? I updated my main post with the mods I made to help fix this. Is it caching?

Comment: It has to do with `$_POST['acceptpost']`. I don't see it anywhere in your form. Write `if(isset($_POST['postnames'])) {`instead.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it. I removed it and kept only the code you gave me and it's giving the same problem.
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8znpe6ke3eadv40/AADmA9qAFvdiUNDWqRdCevcHa?dl=0

Look there and you can see my latest code. You can see how it all works at http://www.itaktical.com/webpreview/jsoblick/

Comment: I edited it a bit and it worked for all of 15 seconds then it went back to not updating after I started commenting out some pretty pointless things?